# Setting the x-axis for R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make the x-axis display the text in the "xaxisTitles" vector?

Here is my code you can run:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)

xaxisTitles<- cbind("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","j","k")
df <- data.frame(time = 1:10,
             a = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
             b = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
             c = cumsum(rnorm(10)))
df <- melt(df ,  id = 'time', variable_name = 'series')

# plot on same grid, each series colored differently -- 
# good if the series have same scale
ggplot(df, aes(time,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = series))+ theme(axis.text.x =     xaxisTitles)
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  Element axis.text.x must be a element_text object.
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are getting the error is that `theme(...)` is used to set the *appearance* of the axis text (e.g., color, font family, font face, size, orientation, etc.), but not the *values* of the text. To do that, as @SteveReno points out, you have to use `scale_x_discrete(...)`.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
set.seed(321)
# xaxisTitles<- cbind("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","j","k")
xaxisTItles<- letters[1:10]   # easier way to do this...
df <- data.frame(time = 1:10,
                 a = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
                 b = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
                 c = cumsum(rnorm(10)))
df <- melt(df ,  id = 'time', variable_name = 'series')

# plot on same grid, each series colored differently -- 
# good if the series have same scale
ggplot(df, aes(time,value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = series))+ 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=xaxisTitles)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(face="bold",colour="red",size=14))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to make the `time` variable a factor rather than a numeric vector, as long as you remember to adjust the `group` aesthetic:

```
df$time = factor(xaxisTitles[df$time])
ggplot(df, aes(time, value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = series, group=series))
```

(If you don't add the `group=series` argument, it won't know that you want to connect lines across the factor on the `x` axis).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use scale_x_discrete to set the labels.

```
ggplot(df, aes(time,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = series))+ scale_x_discrete(labels= xaxisTitles)
```

Here's some more helpful info http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_discrete.html